# Emulator in eclipse won't run project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

EDIT:  Got past a few of the problems by fixing version, however still getting an error as the program very briefly opens before it is forced closed. I've uploaded a screenshot of the errors given in the logcat: http://i44.tinypic.com/2ci70w4.png

--
I've imported a downloaded project into eclipse, and have the correct sdk as I've run stuff on the emulator previously. This however refuses to run. If anyone wants the actual package, I can link you to it if you'd be so kind as to take a look at it (it's only a six or so files of very brief code). Anyway these are the messages I get in the console when I run. Any help is much much appreciated.

---

```
2012-02-08 20:46:46 - GoalManager] ------------------------------
[2012-02-08 20:46:46 - GoalManager] Android Launch!
[2012-02-08 20:46:46 - GoalManager] adb is running normally.
[2012-02-08 20:46:46 - GoalManager] Performing com.android.sample.goalmanager.LoginActivity activity launch
[2012-02-08 20:46:46 - GoalManager] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'droidX2'
[2012-02-08 20:46:46 - GoalManager] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'droidX2'
[2012-02-08 20:46:50 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
[2012-02-08 20:46:50 - Emulator] 
[2012-02-08 20:46:50 - GoalManager] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-02-08 20:46:50 - GoalManager] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-02-08 20:46:51 - GoalManager] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.android.sample.goalmanager.LoginActivity activity launch'!
```

Comment: Is there an error message in the logcat?

Comment: Yes there are quite a few. I've upload them here: http://i44.tinypic.com/2ci70w4.png
Thank you

Comment: You should post the __all__ text from logcat. From what I can see, the critical line is probably the one where it says `java.lang.RuntimeException unable to start activity Component`... However, the line is cut off after that, but it probably indicates where it is failing.

Comment: It seems to be caused by the SQLiteException "unable to open", but it is also cut off. Try exporting the log instead of making a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not with the project but with the emulator. Try to recreate an AVD. I met this problem before and I guess this helped me.

Comment: Tried, no luck sadly. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Check your OS environment variable.

> echo $ADBHOST

Comment: Hi, not particularly sure what this is, would you possibly be able to direct me further? Thank you.

Comment: Do you develop under windows environment? 
I am develop in linux and when i set ADBHOST by mistake eclipse will can't connect to device.